# I want to divide records in table with specific group size in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example, I have one TABLE1 with huge numbers of records,
ID is primary key

| ID | Col1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x |
| 2 | 2 | y |
| 3 | 2 | z |
| 4 | 3 | a |
| 5 | 4 | b |
| 6 | 5 | c |
| 7 | 5 | d |

so on....

Now i have empty table TABLE2 with additional column counter

| ID | COL1 | COL2 | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to fill TABLE2 from TABLE1 with counter set as 1 for first n record and 2 for next n records and so on.
'n' is variable here holding value of group size

Let n = 2 and when we fill TABLE2 then
Expected Result

| ID | COL1 | COL2 | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | y | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | z | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | a | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | b | 3 |
| 6 | 5 | c | 3 |
| 7 | 5 | d | 4 |

Comment: What is your current attempt?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like COL2 is irrelevant. What is the rule for Counter?

Comment: i used NTILE but it is giving me different result, like for 62 records and n = 10, i am getting for first 11 records counter = 1, for next 11 = 2, for next 10 = 3,10 = 4,10 = 5,10 = 6 but i need for first 10 =1,next 10 = 2, 10 = 3, 10 = 4, 10 =5, 10 =6, and last 2 records will have counter = 7

Comment: Col1 , Col2 are additional column yeah not relevant to problem. Rule for counter is simple like for first n records counter will have 1, for next n records counter will have 2 and so on.  Here n is size of group

Comment: All you need is `( Id + 1 ) / 2 as Counter`. (Generically: `( Id + N - 1 ) / N`.) Of course your `Id` column is always a thing of beauty with no missing values, right? And it provides the "first"/"next" order you mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

Just insert the result of this into your new table:

```
SELECT *
     , ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)-1) / 2) + 1 AS n0
  FROM t1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(ID,COL1,COL2,counter)
SELECT ID,COL1,COL2,
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) / n + 1)
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: You realize `OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` is logical nonsense. You are directing the engine to order the rows any way it wants. The result can - and likely will at the worst possible time - be an order that you do not expect or desire. And you will be confused because it "always worked previously".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE   (ID int, Col1 int, COL2 char(1))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE   (ID int, Col1 int, COL2 char(1), [Counter] int)
;
DECLARE @N int = 2;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    VALUES  
            (1, 1,  'x')
        ,   (2, 2,  'y')
        ,   (3, 2,  'z')
        ,   (4, 3,  'a')
        ,   (5, 4,  'b')
        ,   (6, 5,  'c')
        ,   (7, 5,  'd')
;
INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT 
        ID
    ,   Col1
    ,   Col2
    ,   [Counter]   =   ((ID-1) / @N) + 1
  FROM @Table1
;

SELECT * FROM @Table2;
```